# Can I set a flag in Hyper-V so that driver software inside VMs does not know it is running within a VM?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, passthrough

I know that VMWare ESXI/vSphere allows setting a flag to hide virtualization detection. I need to install NVidia drivers in a VM that do not run when virtualization is detected. This does not violate any end user agreements and hence I wonder whether this is now possible with Hyper-V?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? There is a whole product line of special GPUs with hypervisor integration, like NVIDIA GRID.

Comment: I am trying to pass through GPUs to VM clients. Particularly non enterprise NVIDIA cards, such as the GTX series. It works perfectly fine with KVM in Linux but Hyper-V stubbornly refuses to pass through consumer NVIDIA cards.

Comment: @John Mahowald, the problem I have is to want to install an NVIDIA video card driver for a consumer card (GTX980ti or 1080ti) inside a vm instance. It works perfectly fine in a non virtualized environment but NVIDIA blocks via software flag the install inside a vm. Some virtualization platforms allow setting a cpu flag to hide the virtualization environment from driver installers, I look for a way to do the same within hyper-v. It seems it is not possible as of now?

Comment: @MatthiasWolf, did you ever succeed? If yes, please share some information.

Comment: @theateist, no, unfortunately not, I aborted running deep neural network training within a vm instance.

Answer (score -4):

Configure the hypervisor to share the GPU. For Hyper-V: [Set up and configure RemoteFX vGPU for Remote Desktop Services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-remotefx-vgpu). Check in Hyper-V manager that the appropriate GPUs have selected **Use this GPU with RemoteFX**. This requires a suitable graphics driver for the host. It also has RDS licensing implications that I'm not qualified to comment on.

A different method is to dedicate the device to the guest. Again Hyper-V:  [Plan for Deploying Devices using Discrete Device Assignment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/plan/plan-for-deploying-devices-using-discrete-device-assignment).  This one has its own requirements including:

> Discrete Device Assignment requires server class hardware that is
>   capable of granting the operating system control over configuring the
>   PCIe fabric (Native PCI Express Control). In addition, the PCIe Root
>   Complex has to support "Access Control Services" or ACS which enables
>   Hyper-V to force all PCIe traffic through the I/O MMU.

If the driver is telling you that it is refusing to run in a guest, despite it having direct assignment of the GPU, take it up with the author (NVidia).

Comment: That does not at all even tangent the question. For what it's worth I passed through my gpu. The driver checks the CPU flag. I stated I am aware Nvidia does that. I asked whether I can set the CPU flag with hyper v as I can with ESXi and other hypervisors.

Comment: Did u ever solve this?

Comment: Also... This answer doesn't qualify as an answer by any means...

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers, that is why I did not mark it as an answer. And no, I aborted the attempt, I now train deep neural networks on a local machine instance and/or at google/amazon's gpu instances.